# "Do you think he can still be alive?", "Can" used for probability, or what?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, modal-verbs

I came across these sentences in [a learner's dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/can) (see examples for sense 3a) today:

> Do you think he *can* still be alive? [= do you think it is possible that he is still alive.]
>
> I don't think he *can* still be alive. [= I think he must be dead.]

Since the second one is negative, it's probably not wrong, as it's pretty much a paraphrase of *I think he can't still be alive.* and *can't* can be used with the sense of *0% probability*, i.e. can't = I'm  certain it's not true.

### The Problem

From what I've known and what I've read, *could*, but **not** *can*, is usually used this way to indicate *probability* either in the present or the future, as in *he coud be in the garden.*

As for possibility, *can* can only be used to tell general possibilities/truths (*It can be rainy here during September.*) or the possibility in a particular situation (We can go to Paris this weekend, since we don't have to work).

### What I Think & What I've Tried Doing

I think the first one should read

> Do you think he could still be alive?

and probably even the second one should read

> I don't think he could still be alive.

However, it seemed strange **to me** (who is a non-native) when I replaced *could* with *may* in the first sentence, which is usually possible when talking about probability.

> *Do you think he may still be alive?

I also noticed that

> Do you think he is still alive?

seemed more natural.

### The Questions

- What is *can* doing there?
- In what context is *can* used like this?
- Can *could* do the job too?

---

**Note**

- I'm talking about using *can* and *could* in the present here. (This may lead to varying answers if I don't make this clear, I think)
- Please, please avoid the word "possible" where possible. If you're going to use it, please make it clear what *kind* of "possible" you mean: generally possible (he can be hard at times), possible in the situation (we can go to Paris this weekend because we don't have to work), possible as in *probability* (he could be in the car.)

Comment: If it's Merriam Webster and saying that *can* can be used that way, why don't we accept it? In fact, seeing this I *learned* that okay, it can be used this way as well!

Comment: This has nothing to do with me accepting the use. I certainly accept the use. The question is about *how* and *when* to use it this way, and *why* they use it that way.

Comment: I just got an idea a moment ago: *can* is used in the examples to state the possibility (as in speculation). Unlike in another example, "Where’s my bag? Have you seen it? – No, but it ?can be in the car.", this can is possible because of the speculation is evidence-based (external). Also, interrogation and negation might be related to the possibility of the use of *can* in the example sentences. In this context, *could* would also work.

Comment: I like the point that interrogation and negation might be related to the possibility of using can (as they are usually grouped together in grammar). I however still think that in your example *could* (or may, or might) can only be in that place. This is just me though. *I haven't gone to bed after all...*

Comment: I think "I think he could still be alive" is more natural. Perhaps they were trying to keep it simple and only explain one thing at a time?

Comment: @DamkerngT. I don't think you could say "it can be in the car". Unfortunately I'm not sure why; it just sounds wrong. However, the "could" in my first sentence can be replaced by "can" and the first "can" in this sentence could be replaced by "could". ;)

Comment: @starplusplus I wrote that comment before I learned how to write a star (\*) in a comment. I wanted to type "No, but it \*can be in the car." (with a star indicating an incorrect usage) but I couldn't, so I typed "No, but it ?can be in the car/" instead. (I told the OP about that in a chat already.) Thanks for the comment anyway. ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sense of *can* is what linguists call a *negative [polarity item](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarity_item)* (NPI). You're already aware that *can't* can be used to mean "is not possible", and you clearly have little difficulty accepting that *can* can be used to mean "is possible" when the context effectively negates it ("I don't think that …"). So the tricky part is just recognizing that in English, negative polarity items are also *licensed by* (i.e., allowed to occur in the context of) questions.

Another negative polarity item is *any*; as you can see from these examples, they have similar distributions:

- Direct negation:

  - *1 isn't greater than any other positive integers.*
  - *2 can't be greater than 3.*
- Negation in a matrix (containing) clause:

  - *I don't think 1 is greater than any other positive integers.*
  - *I don't think that 2 can be greater than 3.*
- A question:

  - *Is 1 greater than any other positive integers?*
  - *Can 2 be greater than 3?*
- Use after *only*:

  - *Only 1 is greater than any other positive integers.* [This is false, of course, but the statement is grammatical.]
  - *Only 2 can be greater than 3.* [Ditto.]

Note that not all NPIs are licensed by the exact same contexts: some require more thoroughly negative contexts than others. Also, a word can be an NPI in one dialect, or in one register, without being an NPI in a different dialect or register. So this is a rough observation, rather than an firm guarantee of identical behavior. But it's a good first approximation.

Answer (score 2):

I'm wondering whether this is a regional variation. The sentence

> *Do you think he can still be alive?

sounds somewhat strange to me.  Instead, I would say

> Do you think he might still be alive?
>
> Do you think he may still be alive?
>
> Do you think he is still alive?

The problem seems to be that "to be alive" is not an action but a state.  That's why

> Do you think he can still swim?
>
> Do you think he can still go out with his friends?
>
> Do you think he can still trick his wife?

are all okay.  But the following sentences seem odd:

*Do you think he can be an American?

*Do you think he can be sick?

*Do you think he can have a green car?

Comment: Could you maybe edit this to highlight the distinction you're making between "can [be state]" and "can [do action]"? I missed the importance on first read and that's why I'm only now +1ing.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are definitely right. Some things in english literature is not what it is supposed to be. There are words like "barely possible", "full empty", etc which has different meaning but we can generally understand it. The word "can" in the sentence

A :- “Do you think John can still be alive?" 
B :- "Yes i think so"

means probability but in a negative sense. A thinks John is dead so he is asking for B's opinion

Answer (score 1):

In questions we can use "can", (to talk about general or specific possibility" , "could", OR "might". We do not use may.
e.g. "I got a bouquet of flowers, but there was no card." "Who can/could/might they be from?' " Do you think they can/could/might be from Frank?" "Do you think that Frank can/could/ might still be alive?"

Answer (score 0):

We cannot argue that *can* can be used that way -the dictionary says. But if you are asking *why*, I can not explain like a grammarian can. However, I can surely put this it in better way that *with negation or in question* one use of *can* is to express **doubt** of something/someone. I'm just trying to help you.

> [can (v) (#1.3)](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/can?q=can) - (with negative or in questions) *Used to express doubt or surprise about the possibility of*

I think it fits to your concern.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with your thinking. In my opinion, the examples given are poor.

> I don't think he can still be alive.

reads much better as

> I don't think he could still be alive.

The problem is that this sense of *can* is usually reserved for **ability** or **action**, whereas being alive is a **state**. See [dynamic verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_verb) (for ability and action) and [stative verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stative_verb) (for state).

Compare with

> I don't think he can drive.

This sounds much more natural because driving is an ability, not a state.

Also

> I don't think he can be good.

Here, "be good" is describing behaviour, therefore an action, whereas "be alive" or "be hungry" are states. It's possible to say "He is **being** good", whereas *"He is **being** alive" and *"He is **being** hungry" are ungrammatical.

The examples on the Learner's Dictionary are not totally incorrect, but are unlikely to be found in most situations.

Answer (score 0):

Both **could** and **can** can be used, but the connotations are a little different.

> Do you think he **could** still be alive?

**Could** refers to probability or likelihood; "How likely is it that he is still alive?".

> Do you think he **can** still be alive?

**Can** refers to possibility, the ability to be alive; "Is it possible that he is still alive?".