# modal word "can"

Tags: modal-verbs

When the modal word "can" is used to express possibility, it is used to express **general possibility or theoretical possibility** rather than **specific possibility**（http://www.englishpage.com/modals/can.html）, for example "Prices can be high in London" is fine since this is theoretical possibility and "He can be on the bus" is not right since this is specific possibility.

My question is whether this usage is **only applied in assertive sentence**. Because I saw a sentence on the website "Can this story be true?" and I think "can" here is used to express specific possibility. So I am wondering "can" could be used to express specific possibility in interrogative sentences. Am i right?

Comment: Related: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/20867/do-you-think-he-can-still-be-alive-can-used-for-probability-or-what

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, then yes, you can often swap "Can" in the beginning of a sentence to "Is it possible" -- "Can this story be true?" => "Is it possible this story could be true?" Or "Can you get me some milk at the store, please?" => "Is it possible for you to get me some milk at the store, please?" (Yes, I know that's also a request form. The synonym still holds, as do synonyms of "Are you willing to," etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

> They may be on the bus.

and

> They might be on the bus.

Both mean:
It is possible that they are on the bus.

(AmE seens to prefer *might*, but only in statements.)

But we don't have a question version of may (= possibility). The following do not work:

1

> *May they be on the bus?

2

> *May this story be true?

And "might" is uncommon in questions.

> Might they be on the bus?

is grammatical, but unusual. Instead, we use  *can* and *could*. *Could* is more usual, but *can* can be used. Sometimes the difference is one of dialect. To me

> Could they be on the bus?

and

> Could this story be true?

are more natural than asking the same thing with *can*. But I'd probably never ask the questions with *might.*

Comment: "May they be on the bus?" is grammatical in other situations, though -- it is asking permission for something to be on the bus. Or, in a more familiar way, "May we be excused from class to go to the bathroom?" (My mother taught our English class. If you asked, "Can I go to the bathroom?" she'd say, "I don't know. *Can* you?" And then you'd have to rephrase it before you got permission.)

Comment: It's hard but not impossible to conceive *May they be on the bus?* as permissive without an adverbial. As in: *May they be on the bus between 10 and 11?* And yes, the prescription against *can* for permission is well-known (I remember the exact moment my 6th grade teacher chided me for asking permission with *can*.) I think, except for in  *If I may*, that *can* can be substituted for *may* in any sentence of permission. What do you say, @A.Beth?

Comment: If I'm understanding your first statement @δοῦλος, I think "I have two dogs; may they be on the bus?" would be a valid request for permission, even without an adverbial. (It'd be a little more correct to say, "May they get on the bus," though considering dogs sometimes charge ahead...) But yes, in common speech -- despite english teachers complaining -- "can" and "may" are interchanged all the time when asking for permission.